# Javascript - understand the fundamentals

Tags: javascript

I've started learning JavaScript, and people keep telling me "UNDERSTAND FUNDAMENTALS" first before you ask about frameworks.

What does it specifically mean when people say "understand the fundamentals" of JavaScript before moving on to more complex stuff?

Somebody also said about JavaScript:

> "Overall, I think my biggest mistake was not mastering the basics before moving on to libraries and frameworks."

Comment: Is this your first programming language? Fundamentals means very different things if we're talking about fundamentals of programming vs fundamentals of js in particular.

Comment: Try codeacademy.com

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fundamentals It means you need to have a very sound understanding of the basics before you move on to something more advanced (which is *exactly* what the second quote you included says). If you're not strong on the fundamentals, you write poor quality code and create many difficulties for yourself which would not happen if you were more solid in the basics.

Comment: In JS it means (in no particular order) Prototypical Inheritance, Functional Scope, Closures, Functions as Objects, DOM Manipulations, Truthieness /Falseyness, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just for your reference, one reason that you might be getting down votes is because your question is based on someone's opinion. There might not be a clear objective answer. You might want to ask the people who made the statement directly what they meant since it's their opinion.

Comment: I disagree that this is "primarily opinion based." (It may include some matters of opinion, but within the help center's range). The question asks for specifics, and while "How to learn JS" would be opinion-based, asking what qualifies as "fundamentals" isn't as bad.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially what people are saying is, you should ***learn the basics of the language before trying to move on to harder things*** as it'll be easier to ask questions and understand the answers when you know why things are written in certain ways.

For example, *jQuery* is a very easy to use framework that can be picked up quickly. However if you don't understand JavaScript basics, things like defining variables and if statements etc, it'll get confusing very quickly with what is doing what and where.

Have a look at [the W3Schools JavaScript tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp). They're quite good and you'll get through a lot quickly as well.

For example, this will write text onto the page...

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My First JavaScript";
</script>
```

This will add 3 to a variable...

```
<script>
    var myVar = 3;
</script>
```

When you learn how they both work, you can add them together.

```
<script>
    var myVar = 3;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My number is " + myVar;
</script>
```

There's loads of resources online, have a search and just go through the tutorials. Some sites may not explain it very well, but others will. Also, make sure to search through the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag. There's a plethora of useful information there too.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there's a bit of irony in this-- people are likely to downvote it, as an understanding of the fundamentals is often required to post a good question here (usually questions posted by people who are just starting out are riddled with misunderstandings).

Basically, understanding the fundamentals means mastering Vanilla (or unmodified) Javascript. People tell you to do this because without understanding the basics, you have no way to apply libraries, frameworks, etc.

This is akin to saying "Why do I have to learn Math to learn Physics or Probability?"

Imagine this: You have a framework that can get some text from a server with `textGetter.getText();`. But how do you write that to the screen? Without basic JS, you wouldn't be able to do that. What if you had to compare it with another string, e.g. "Hello", and respond based on that? Would you use `=`, `==`, or `===`? Using the first would always return true, so the response would always happen.

**TL;DR:** You need to know how to play a board game to be able to add your own rules.

Here are some useful resources:

- [Why you should learn basic JS first](https://snipcart.com/blog/learn-vanilla-javascript-before-using-js-frameworks)
- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/)
- [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript)
- [Google (More useful than you might think at first)](http://www.google.com)
- [Javascript: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do) (This is my personal preference, as it's how I learned)
- And, probably most importantly: Practice, practice, practice! I know people tell you this all the time, but it's actaully true in this case. Trust me. Make games. Make webpages. Make whatever you want. Then improve it. Hopefully, this will keep pushing you just a little bit out of your comfort zone; this is when Google becomes one of your best friends.

PS-- I've given you a free pass with the downvoting; other users are a little too harsh to newbies IMO.

Comment: "First of all, there's a bit of irony in this-- people are likely to downvote it, as an understanding of the fundamentals is often required to post a good question here (usually questions posted by people who are just starting out are riddled with misunderstandings)." thank you. i was wondering why i got downvoted for no reason. How can a newbie ask "right" question other than ask questions that sound like newbie? People are too harsh towards newbie around here. Everybody started from somewhere. When i learn enough of this stuff, i'll make sure i am not harsh to a newbie.

Comment: Good idea, that's what I'm doing. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are already a programmer in any of other languages then you can follow https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/javascript-fundamentals

Comment: Don't point users to expensive (or even overpriced) bundles when free versions of all the parts, and possibly even the whole thing, are available for free online at just one Search of a Google.